How to replicate system tap highlighting and animation
I'm creating a custom ButtonStyle, and I want to replicate the iOS button highlighting that occurs on tap. (iOS 17)
(Backstory: I'm using a custom ButtonStyle because I want to apply a minimum width to the button, using a .bordered or .borderedProminent ButtonStyle will produce an incorrect button size, presumably because those styles introduce their own padding, which conflicts with the framing.)
I've seen people adjust the button's opacity and brightness like this:
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let backgroundColor: Color = .mint
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    
        configuration.label
            .frame(minWidth: 240)
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 19))
            .fontDesign(.rounded)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                
            .background(backgroundColor, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
        
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1)
            .brightness(configuration.isPressed ? 0.2 : 0)
    }
}

Problem: this approach doesn't provide reliable/usable/readable highlighting across a range of colors. It will work well for a red or dark blue background, but is barely readable with a background color of, say, mint.
This is especially notable in Dark Mode.
Whereas Apple's highlighting is readable regardless of the color, across Light/Dark mode.
(Note: the problem still occurs if no .brightness modification is used.)
Any suggestions?

I don't think the system button changes brightness though? Just remove the brightness adjustment and it looks the same as a system .borderedProminent button in my eyes, at least for mint.

@Sweeper Thanks for the response. If I remove the brightness modifier, the difference is much more noticable in Dark Mode. i.e. in Dark Mode, using a custom approach with reducing opacity, the button will become darker on a dark background. But the system approach doesn't do that. The button actually becomes brighter. Cheers.
